# fcm keeping App up to date in background on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

**Background**

I have an App, for Android and iOS. This App can be used to track time and score of a match. A nice feature is when other users of Android and iOS can subscribe to the match and get updates through FCM when the score of the match changes for example. All match logic is inside the App and not on a server.
It is functioning beautifully on Android devices.

**Issue**

On iOS devices, updates are received normally when the App is in the foreground, but (although background notifications and background processing is turned on) as soon as the App is longer than x minutes in the background or the phone is going to the lock-screen or asleep, problems occur. Updates are no longer received or received with (very) great delay. Defeating the purpose of the updates through FCM. Use case: user uses the App, at some point puts the phone into his/her pocket and some time later checks the App again, but if updates are missed, the data displayed is useless.

**What I’ve already looked at**

I've read everything there is about it on the Apple site and on this website. In FCM you can set the content_available attribute and/or apns-priority header. When setting apns-priority header of 10, my message gets rejected, because that only seems to work when you also set the badge, alert etc in the message, not for silent background updates.
So I tried turning the badge on or also setting a notification message in my FCM MulticastMessage. Either options result that the phone displays the new badge or notification, but somehow the App is not triggered to also process the data attached in the same FCM message. Looks like it gets discarded somewhere and/or iOS doesn’t trigger the messaging callback in the App.

**Code used to send the message**

Using Python the code below is used to send the message. Some lines are commented out, those were used to test with.

```
newmessage = messaging.MulticastMessage(
    data = mycustomdata,
    notification = messaging.Notification(title = 'Title', body = 'Body message'),
    tokens = devicetokens,
    android = messaging.AndroidConfig(priority = 'high'),
    apns = messaging.APNSConfig(
        #headers = {'apns-priority': '10', 'apns-collapse-id': message['code']},
        #payload = messaging.APNSPayload(aps = messaging.Aps(badge=1, content_available=1))
        headers = {'apns-collapse-id': message['code']},
        payload = messaging.APNSPayload(aps = messaging.Aps(content_available=1))
    ))
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to send a multicastmessage with FCM for both Android and iOS devices that would have a apns-priority of 10 for iOS devices where my custom data will still gets processed by the App? With or without a badge, sound or alert?
2. It looks like Apple is trying to defer all logic to a remote server and have that server send device-tailored updates. Is it true that because of this my current setup will never work when the App is (longer than x minutes) in the background or phone is on lock-screen or asleep for iOS devices?

**Possible solution**

If the answer to question #2 is yes, then the only way this will ever work is that I will send device-tailored notification alerts and as soon as the App resumes from sleep/background it will request the latest updates using an API call. Correct? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Yes. Use approach 2. Rather than sending silent "content-available" messages which can be throttled, just send regular push notifications so that iOS displays the content for you. You can use the `apns-collapse-id` header to overwrite previous notifications.